# Bootstrap 4 Image slider to add forms cant do small size and center

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, angular6

I used my **angular 6** project landing page to [bootstrap 4 carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/carousel/), carousel is working fine, and i added some form like a [booking.com](http://booking.com) , i have some issue that forms is cant do the small size and center

anyone know how to do that like as booking.com

my code part

```css
.section .section-center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}



#booking::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}

.booking-form {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.booking-form>form .row.no-margin {
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.booking-form>form .row.no-margin>[class*="col-"] {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.booking-form .form-group {
  position: relative;
  padding: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.booking-form .form-group:after {
  content: '';
  background: rgba(129, 131, 144, 0.15);
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 75px;
}

.booking-form .form-control {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: none;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #222;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 0;
}

.booking-form .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #818390;
}

.booking-form .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #818390;
}

.booking-form .form-control::placeholder {
  color: #818390;
}

.booking-form input[type="date"].form-control:invalid {
  color: #818390;
}

.booking-form select.form-control {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.booking-form select.form-control+.select-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 30px;
  width: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #818390;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.booking-form select.form-control+.select-arrow:after {
  content: '\279C';
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.booking-form .form-label {
  color: #07c;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.booking-form .form-btn {
  padding: 25px;
}

.booking-form .submit-btn {
  background: #07c;
  border: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
}






















/* GLOBAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Padding below the footer and lighter body text */

body {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}


/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  bottom: 3rem;
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel-item {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 110px);
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 110px);
}


/* MARKETING CONTENT
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */
.marketing .col-lg-4 {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
  margin-right: .75rem;
  margin-left: .75rem;
}


/* Featurettes
------------------------- */

.featurette-divider {
  margin: 5rem 0; /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
}

/* Thin out the marketing headings */
.featurette-heading {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -.05rem;
}


/* RESPONSIVE CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */

@media (min-width: 40em) {
  /* Bump up size of carousel content */
  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }

  .featurette-heading {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 62em) {
  .featurette-heading {
    margin-top: 7rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-----------------------Header--------------------------------->



<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">header</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">

    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-----------------------Header--------------------------------->
<main role="main">


  <div id="booking" class="section">
      <div class="section-center">




  <div class="row " style="z-index: 99999;  top: 40%;
 position: absolute; color: white; left: 100px; right: 5%; margin: 0px;">
    <div class="booking-form col-12" >
      <form >
        <div class="row col-12">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <span class="form-label">Location</span>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Location">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">




                <div class="form-group">
                  <span class="form-label">Event Type</span>
                  <select class="form-control">
                    <option>Event 1</option>
                    <option>Event 1</option>
                    <option>Event 1</option>
                  </select>
                  <span class="select-arrow"></span>
                </div>


          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-btn">
              <button class="submit-btn">Check</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>


    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="first-slide" src="/assets/images/background.jpg" alt="First slide">
        <div class="container">


          <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
            <h1>Example headline.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="second-slide" src="/assets/images/background.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="third-slide" src="/assets/images/background.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-right">
            <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>




      </div>

    <!-- /END THE FEATURETTES -->

  <!-- /.container -->

      </div>

</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for extra row (`<div class="row " style="z-index: 99999;  top: 40%;
 position: absolute; color: white; left: 100px; right: 5%; margin: 0px;">`)
instead add a div(here: `form-wrapper` ) and add some css for positioning div at center

```css
.section .section-center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}



#booking::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}

.booking-form {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.booking-form>form .row.no-margin {
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.booking-form>form .row.no-margin>[class*="col-"] {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.booking-form .form-group {
  position: relative;
  padding: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.booking-form .form-group:after {
  content: '';
  background: rgba(129, 131, 144, 0.15);
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 75px;
}

.booking-form .form-control {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: none;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #222;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 0;
}

.booking-form .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #818390;
}

.booking-form .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #818390;
}

.booking-form .form-control::placeholder {
  color: #818390;
}

.booking-form input[type="date"].form-control:invalid {
  color: #818390;
}

.booking-form select.form-control {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.booking-form select.form-control+.select-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 30px;
  width: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #818390;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.booking-form select.form-control+.select-arrow:after {
  content: '\279C';
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.booking-form .form-label {
  color: #07c;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.booking-form .form-btn {
  padding: 25px;
}

.booking-form .submit-btn {
  background: #07c;
  border: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
}






















/* GLOBAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Padding below the footer and lighter body text */

body {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}


/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  bottom: 3rem;
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel-item {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 110px);
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 110px);
}


/* MARKETING CONTENT
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */
.marketing .col-lg-4 {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
  margin-right: .75rem;
  margin-left: .75rem;
}


/* Featurettes
------------------------- */

.featurette-divider {
  margin: 5rem 0; /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
}

/* Thin out the marketing headings */
.featurette-heading {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -.05rem;
}


/* RESPONSIVE CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */

@media (min-width: 40em) {
  /* Bump up size of carousel content */
  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }

  .featurette-heading {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 62em) {
  .featurette-heading {
    margin-top: 7rem;
  }
}

.form-wrapper {
  z-index: 99999;
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    left: 50%;
    right: auto;
    margin: 0px;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-----------------------Header--------------------------------->



<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">header</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">

    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-----------------------Header--------------------------------->
<main role="main">


  <div id="booking" class="section">
      <div class="section-center">




  <div class="form-wrapper ">
    <div class="booking-form" >
      <form >
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <span class="form-label">Location</span>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Location">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">




                <div class="form-group">
                  <span class="form-label">Event Type</span>
                  <select class="form-control">
                    <option>Event 1</option>
                    <option>Event 1</option>
                    <option>Event 1</option>
                  </select>
                  <span class="select-arrow"></span>
                </div>


          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-btn">
              <button class="submit-btn">Check</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>


    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="first-slide" src="/assets/images/background.jpg" alt="First slide">
        <div class="container">


          <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
            <h1>Example headline.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="second-slide" src="/assets/images/background.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="third-slide" src="/assets/images/background.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-right">
            <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>




      </div>

    <!-- /END THE FEATURETTES -->

  <!-- /.container -->

      </div>

</main>
```

Comment: Hello Nidi, Thanks for your solution , its work for me